# Different MD5 hash for same string (CryptoJS.MD5)

Tags: amazon-web-services, md5, cryptojs

Using **CryptoJS** I am calculating **MD5** of the string at the bottom of this post,  and send it to Amazon web services, however the **MD5** value that I calculate, and the amazon calculates differs.

So I did some online tests, and realized that MD5 calculation differs in some md5 calculating websites too. For example, **md5hashgenerator** calculates same value with me, and **onlinemd5** calculates same value as amazon.

What I need is to get the same MD5 value of Amazon using CryptoJS

**- CryptoJS.MD5:** ec20007986ee9e1a5152c35d07e87fcc

**- Amazon Scratchpad MD5:** ee288aa4858481d7b1d7422c6fc4b3af

**- md5hashgenerator.com:** ec20007986ee9e1a5152c35d07e87fcc

**- onlinemd5.com:** ee288aa4858481d7b1d7422c6fc4b3af

---

**String to calculate MD5:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_EXAMPLE_123456</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>56789</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>ASIN</Type>
        <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
        <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
        <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
        <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
        <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
        <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
        <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Health>
          <ProductType>
            <HealthMisc>
              <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
              <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
            </HealthMisc>
          </ProductType>
        </Health>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

**Edit:** After some test, I realised that the difference is caused because of the "newline" character. So the question is why newline is treated differently in those tools and how can I achieve the same results with Amazon using CryptoJS?

Answer (score 5):

md5 (and other hashing functions like sha*, Murmur...) work with binary data. Hence, how you convert your text to binary will change the resulting hash. Obviously, the same text in UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 will have different hash.

The case of newline is a bit more tricky. In the ancient time, people had to do two keystroke on their typewriter to get a newline: Carriage Return, that put the printhead back at the beginning of the line while staying at the same vertical position, and Line Feed that moved the printhead down one line, while staying at the same horizontal position.

In early computer days, people mimicked this, and US-ASCII has two codepoints regarding line termination: CR (0x0D) and LF (0x0A). A newline was made with the famous CRLF sequence. The HTTP/1.0 standard for example required CRLF as a separator between headers (I didn't check HTTP/1.1 nor HTTP/2).

Then people started thinking two characters for a single concept was a waste, and Unix systems started to use only LF, while Mac systems (before OS X) used only CR (and Windows, well, thought you had enough memory for all those superfluous bytes).

So I stored your text in a file called "tmp" on my Ubuntu computer, using LF as the line separator, and:

```
$ md5sum tmp 
ee288aa4858481d7b1d7422c6fc4b3af  tmp
$ unix2dos tmp 
unix2dos: converting file tmp to DOS format...
$ md5sum tmp 
ec20007986ee9e1a5152c35d07e87fcc  tmp
```

Voilà!!

(unix2dos is a tool for converting LF to CRLF).

Answer (score 3):

The returned hash differs due to the newline character. You can trim and remove all white spaces in the string before applying the md5 hash. This way the result should be the same. Here is an implementation with CryptoJS:

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

let string = "xmlString".replace(/\s+/g, '');
let hash = CryptoJS.MD5(string).toString();
console.log(hash);
```

I don't know why newline is treated differently in the tools you used but after removing white spaces got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

One guess would be that it has to do with the other providers [salting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) the payload (in this case the stringified XML) before hashing. I don't see much documentation as they are all small free online tools. It's good to be explicit about that as it can lead to situations like this where you can't confirm a hash on your side that was calculated with a different salt value, even though the payload is the same.

CryptoJS [doesn't seem to have implemented salt addition](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/md5.js) as an explicit feature.

Comment: Meanwhile I am doing some tests on those online sites, and I realized that, "new line", is creating different hashs. I did some tests with the example string. If I use two lines from the top, they create different hash, if I only use the top line from example string, both websites create same hash. So I am trying to understand why new line is causing such a thing.

Comment: That sounds like each provider has his own way of serializing the XML input, where occasional double lines are omitted, for example. That would certainly create a problem on its own because there are different ways it gets converted into a string in the different providers, and different payloads result in different hashes.